# doxygen generated makefile references missing utility - docsetutil

Tags: documentation, doxygen, redhat

trying to build documentation for a project.

the project uses the doxygen product which rpm contains the /usr/bin/docsetutil binary?  Doxygen 1.8.4 generated output Makefile is looking for it...

thx.

Answer (score 2):

That binary is part of the OS X / macOS developer toolchain. On my OS X 10.9.5 system, it exists at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/docsetutil`.

I don't know of a workaround for other platforms, so you'll probably want to have a `Makefile` or a separate `Doxyfile` or something that just doesn't attempt to build the docset unless you're on an OS X system. And just build the docsets on a Mac, if you have access to one.

It will be interesting to see if a Free replacement `docsetutil` for GNU/Linux ever pops up, now that the Dash developer has [opened the door](https://blog.kapeli.com/dash-for-ios-android-windows-or-linux) for offline documentation browsers on other platforms to use his docsets (*e.g.*, [Zeal](https://zealdocs.org/)). As far as I know (and I don't know much), the Dash web site at [kapeli.com](https://kapeli.com/dash) is acting as the central repository at the moment.

**ref**: I had the same question, and discovered the answer in [this](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/37427) otherwise unrelated bug report for the TYPO3 CMS. I'm leaving this answer here for other folks who find this by way of a search engine.